# How to verify that a string has characters belonging to an alphabet?

Tags: python, alphabet

I have this code:

```
ALPHABET = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + ' _'

def is_correct(mystr):
    # check if the characters in mystr belong to the ALPHABET
    # return True or False
```

What I would do is:

1. Get alphabet of mystr: `alphabet1`
2. Check if all characters in `alphabet1` are in ALPHABET

But I do not know how to do 1) How to get the alphabet of a given string?
And how to know if `alphabet1` is in `ALPHABET`?

Answer (score 2):

```
ALPHABET = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + ' _'

def is_correct(mystr):
    return set(mystr).issubset(set(ALPHABET))
```

OR

```
def is_correct(mystr):
    return all(c in ALPHABET for c in mystr)
```

OR

```
def is_correct(mystr):
    for char in mystr:
        if char not in ALPHABET:
            return False
    return True
```

OR

```
def is_correct(mystr):
    mystr = set(mystr)
    for char in ALPHABET:
        mystr.discard(char)
    return not mystr
```

Comment: You should make `ALPHABET` a set by default, so all the other `in ALPHABET` are O(1) too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use function isalpha - it will check if character (or string) is a letter. You don't have to declare your alphabet

```
def has_letters(str1):
    str2= list(str1)
    for i in str2:
        if i.isalpha:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: I want my alphabet to be flexible